# Metasploit payload problem

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

Recently I tested a shell vector payload. A text file converted to .bat, which is both theoretically and practically 100% undetectable by antivirus. First I tested it on my host computer for Kali Linux VM and it worked, I got the meterpreter session. But I tried it also on a friend's computer and it isn't working. After clicking it, nothing happens in Kali Linux's terminal: I don't get the meterpreter session. Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Please differentiate between the Linux distro you're using and Metasploit, which is a completely independent program from Linux.

Comment: You need to describe the networking between the VM and your friend's computer. Does your VM have network access to your target? Can you ping it? Can it ping you? Do you have proof that it ran at all on your friend's computer?

Comment: Yeah, she said she clicked it... and saw a black pop-up which fastly dissapeared, just like on my computer. She is like... 200 km far from me. the distance is a problem? Why i should ping her? i know that... you don't have to know target's ip if you use a payload, right?

Comment: In order for the meterpreter to send back a session the target computer and yours need a network connection!! Your VM is behind a heck of a lot of layers. She can't get to your computer. What IP did you put in the meterpreter settings as the LHOST?

Comment: My ip from ifconfig. 192.168.1.7

Comment: Ok, you need to take a big step backwards from this. You are missing a lot of critical knowledge for any of this to work. First step, you need to learn basic networking. Your questions are the equivalent of wanting to know what exit to get off on to get to a city 200km away, but you don't know what a car ignition key looks like. I could tell you what the exit number is, but you need to get your license first.

Comment: Ok, so you said that it works on my computer because it's right here, and doesn't works on her computer, because it's too for. I understand that, but i don't see what's wrong with LHOST... it should be always my ip from ifconfig, right? And please master, tell me what's the exit number, i'm just a noob, who wants to learn. Any information will be appreciated

Comment: Dude, you're sticking your key in your house's door lock and wondering why the car isn't starting. It's not about distance, it's about having a connection. 192.186.* is a private address and doesn't work over the Internet. You need a direct connection, an external IP, and port forwarding on your router. And no, I'm not going to explain that. You are on the wrong forum for the help you need.

Comment: I understand now, things are more clear, can you give me a link or something where i can learn more? about port forwarding, i mean something like, which port should i use, how to forward a port and so on? yeah, i know that i can search on google, but i think that you are more capable to find something easier for a noob like me, and sorry if i've done something wrong, as i said, i want just to learn.

Comment: Spend some time looking up "TCP/IP" for beginners. It's a huge topic, but hopefully you can find some light material to trigger some thoughts.

Comment: I watched some tutorials about TCP/IP, and now things are more clear. I set up my external ip instead of my internal ip, and i also port forwarding the specific port, but still don't work.. now it doesn't work, not even on my computer. What internal ip i should use when i forward a port? ip from my system or ip from virtual box? i mean from my virtual system. I tested my port on canyouseeme.org and it works only with my real machine's ip, with virtual box system ip it didn't work... so i guess i should keep that ip, but it's not the same as the one from virtual box and things are confusing...